# onErrorResumeNext type inference failed

Tags: rx-java2

If my single errors because of a networkexception return Single.just(false)

If my single errors because of another reason return Single.error

If my single succeeds return the original Single value.

this should be as easy as

```
getStudent(studentId)
    .onErrorResumeNext { if (it is NetworkException) return @onErrorResumeNext Single.just(true)
     return Single.error(it) }
```

Type inference failed.  Expected type mismatch SingleSource found Single

Answer (score 0):

Your Single needs to return the same type as your source (I'm assuming `getStudent()` isn't returning a Boolean). If you want to represent a "success" and "error" states, Kotlin has a `Result` class just for this.

E.g.

```
getStudent()
    .map { student ->
        // Your logic here may look different
        Result.success(student)
    }
    .onErrorResumeNext { error ->
        if (error is NetworkException){
            Single.just(Result.failure(error))
        } else {
            Single.error(error)
        }
    }
```

This will catch network errors and wrap the exception in a `Result`, all other exceptions will be propagated downstream. You can then choose how to handle the error in your `subscribe` method.

Depending on your use case however, you may want to also look into using `Maybe` or the `retry()` operator.